# Cannot access to port 22 of a Raspberry Pi through port forwarding

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, portforwarding

First of all, I've searched many other posts about this issue, but nothing resolved the problem.

I have an issue accessing the ssh port of the raspberry pi 3b+ remotely through the port forwarding. I've been working with PIs and I've often remotely accessed to Pi using the port forwarding options. So I think I'm not making common mistakes, but cannot figure out what the problem is.

My Raspberry Pi 3B+ and laptop are connected to the router via LAN connection.
So I can access to pi SSH port (22) on my laptop through `<Pi's local IP>:22`.
To remotely access to the Pi, I set the router to forward the port 16000 from the outside to the Pi's port 22.
But the connection was refused if I'm to connect to the `<router's public IP>:16000`.

Here are what I've figured out.

- I tried other ports such as 16001, 17000, 16666, ... and ended up with the same issue.
- I used another raspberry pi (Pi 3B, installing Raspbian 10 buster) and got the same issue. Since this Pi was successfully accessed in the past when I used other routers, it seems the router is the problem.
- I checked if the port is blocked by the router. But I could access to my laptop by forwarding the port 16000 to 3389, which is assigned for the 'Windows remote desktop', or the mstsc. So it is unlikely the router blocks the 16000 port.
- I've changed the ssh port of the Pi, by modifying the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and typing `service sshd restart`. I could see the Pi is listening the changed port using the command `sudo netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep sshd`. Nothing changed.
- Changed the LAN connection to the Wifi connection and it was all the same.

Notes

- The raspberry pi 3b+ is installed with the latest Raspberry Pi OS.
- The wifi router is LG U+Net Wifi router CAPL-6000.

Are there any idea of solving or identifying the problem?

Comment: Most gateways (what you call a router) do not allow traffic to flow from inside the network if it is destined to the outside interface. Are you actually outside of your network when you try to access the Pi from the gateway's outside interface, or are you still on the internal LAN?

Comment: Make sure you are forwarding TCP traffic, ssh uses TCP as the protocol, if you are only forwarding UDP it will likely not work

Comment: @stevieb You saved my day. I tried accessing my Pi in other PC in my office and it worked! I've never know that